# how to add text area and checkbox before order details on Woocommerce checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, edit, checkout

I want to add some one check box, one text area and one link before the order details on checkout. I tried to find all over the stackoverflow but I did not found any exact information or code. If anyone help me so I will be very thankful to you. check screen shot for more info http://prntscr.com/9dtloy

`add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'skyverge_before_paying_notice' );
function skyverge_before_paying_notice() {
    wc_print_notice( __( 'Here is some text', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
}`

I tried this code which is showing something like this http://prntscr.com/9dttsi

Thanks

Comment: You must show us what you have tried.

Comment: `add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'skyverge_before_paying_notice' );
function skyverge_before_paying_notice() {
 wc_print_notice( __( 'Here is some text', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
}`

I tried this code which is showing something like this http://prntscr.com/9dttsi

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total', 'my_custom_fields' );

```
function my_custom_fields(){
    // put your custom fields out here
}
```

Comment: It is showing after the your order total text I want to show before the order total text http://prntscr.com/9dyrhl

Answer (score 1):

The following hook will add the text **before the order details** but below the "Your order" text.

```
//Hook
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart_contents', 'fields_before_order_details');

//function
function fields_before_order_details(){
  wc_print_notice( __( 'Here is some text', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
}
```

This is not the only hook that will achieve this, you can find a list of more Woocommerce hooks [here](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html).

Comment: Is there anyway to add content before the your order text ?

Comment: I see you have already found the correct hook, glad to be of some help.

Answer (score 1):

This is how we can show content right before the "Your Order"

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'fields_before_order_details');
//function
function fields_before_order_details(){
  echo 'Terms &amp; Conditions';
}
```

Thanks all for your contribution